# How to add current location to a wall post

Tags: windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I've managed to post a photo with a message to my wall using the Facebook C# SDK. The next step is to add my current location to the post. I'm using Windows Phone 7.1. I have a Geocode location available which I want to add to the post. I can't find how to add a location parameter to the post. Any form of location would be fine, e.g. "Amsterdam".  Is this possible at all?

Here's a piece of code where I would like to add some location magic.

```
    var photoDetails = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    photoDetails.Add("message", txtMessage.Text);
    photoDetails.Add("image", selectedImage);
    // add location

    fb.PostAsync("/photos", photoDetails);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comment by **nsiomos** on [this](http://nocturnsoft.com/devblog/?p=906) blog post, adding locations to the wall post just isn't supported yet by the Graph API of Facebook. I certainly hope this will soon be added as a feature for 3rd party apps using Facebook. My only (quite less charming) option left is just paste the location in the message instead of passing it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I found this link searching a way to get the nearest location from the GeoCoordinates i hope this will help you.

And if you have the location then you can add it to the message.

[Simple GPS Locator](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/241802-simple-gps-locator/)

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain my problem very well. My problem is I can't add a location to the message.

Comment: So you want to add the location information somewhere else or you can't combine it to the message?

Comment: I can't combine it to the message. When you look at Facebook some messages say on the bottom "posted near Amsterdam" for example. After some searching I found out it just isn't supported yet. When you create your own app only the app name will appear

Comment: Yes i understand, and i know now what you wanted to do, i thought you wanted simply combine the pictures title with the locations. Hopefully it will be available soon